# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined Postgres / Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to create connection to remote DB using Sequelize ORM.  But getting an error:

```
> var eventName = msg.name === 'error' ? 'errorMessage' : msg.name
>                       ^
> 
> at Socket.<anonymous> (node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:120:27) at
> emitOne (events.js:116:13) at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7) at
> addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12) at readableAddChunk
> (_stream_readable.js:250:11) at Socket.Readable.push
> (_stream_readable.js:208:10) at TCP.onread (net.js:597:20)
```

I am syncing Sequelize models in server.js, giving a port and passing controller and function.

```
 models.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
        app.listen(1234);
        app.use('/check', check);
        check.testCheck(() => {
            io.emit('testCheck');
         });
    })
```

Here is Sequelize options (all parametres are qorrect meaning: username password db etc.) in models/index.js here I also define models (in this case I have just one model called "orders")

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
    const sequelize = new Sequelize('db', "username", 'password',    {
      host: 'host',
      dialect: 'postgres',
      port: 1234,
      pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
      },
         });

  var models = {
    orders: sequelize['import']("./iSOMessagesModel"),
  }; 



Object.keys(models).forEach(modelName => {
  if (models[modelName].associate) {
    models[modelName].associate(models);
  }
});

models.sequelize = sequelize;
models.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = models;
```

Model looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Orders = sequelize.define('ISOMessages', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    message: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
    },  
    status: {
      type:  DataTypes.STRING
    },
    sResponse: {
      type:  DataTypes.STRING
    },
    userId: {
      type:  DataTypes.INTEGER 
    },
    cardId: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    amount: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER 
    },
    commission: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER 
    },
    location: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    provider: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    }, {
       tableName: 'ISOMessages'
    });


  return Orders;
}
```

Thnx

Comment: have you checked which port your postgres is listening on - default port is 5432..

Comment: @iLuvLogix yes ports is correct